# How to write a conditional mapping in VIM?

Tags: vim, key-bindings

I want to do `nnoremap Q :q!<cr>` and `nnnoremap Q :bd<CR>`, how can i mix these two bindings?
What i ideally want is to make the `Q` binding smart enough to know when we are in a buffer, and when this is the last buffer in the window.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `map <expr>` (`:h map-<expr>`) is your friend.

```
nnoremap <expr> Q yourConditionExpression ? ':q!<cr>':':bd<cr>'
```

In above

```
yourConditionExpression
```

could be an boolean expression E.g. `3>0` or a function returns boolean. You can put the checking logic in there.

Comment: Good idea. But this appears to call `yourConditionExpression` only once - when the .vimrc file is read. For example, if the mapping is `nnoremap <expr> <F12> MyFunc == 0() ? ':Yep' : 'Nope'`, then once the keybinding is read, pressing F12 always returns the same result, even though executing `:echom MyFunc()` returns different results.

Comment: @BrentFaust try `nnoremap <expr> <F12> MyFunc()` and let your `MyFunc()` return the key strokes (characters). I didn't test though. But it should not be a problem, since in my settings I have `getchar()` in function, if it is gonna be evaluated only once,  it won't work.

Comment: You're correct - it _always_ calls the function. It's just that there were errors in my function that needs to change the focused pane: `exe "normal! \<c-w>l"` gives the error *E523: Not allowed here* (in a noremap <expr>).